# Xbox won't leave dev mode

Tags: uwp, xbox

I have an Xbox in devmode and when I open the Dev Home app and select Leave dev mode, it just goes back to the Xbox home screen. Any other ways to force it to leave dev mode?

Answer (score 1):

We're apologize, unfortunately there is a bug.

The workaround is:

In the Leave Dev Mode dialog, if you uncheck the "Delete side loaded games and apps" checkbox and then click okay you will be able to leave Dev Mode.

Comment: Thanks Gersh. This works for me most of the time...sometimes it doesn't. I've found that signing out in combination with this works in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Click Leave developer mode will restart your console in Retail Mode. The Developer Mode is not completely deactivate. After you switch to retail mode, now you can deactivate your console by using one of the following methods.

- [Deactivate your console using the Dev Mode Activation app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-deactivation#deactivate-your-console-using-the-dev-mode-activation-app)
- [Reset your console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-deactivation#reset-your-console)
- [Deactivate your console using Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-deactivation#deactivate-your-console-using-windows-dev-center)

You will no longer use your console for development if you done these.

Comment: Right, except my issue is that the Leave dev mode button isn't working. As I said in my question, clicking it, just goes back to the Xbox start screen...no restart.

Comment: @Scott, is your Xbox is a retail version or a inter-testing version?

Comment: My Xbox is retail

Comment: @Scott, I'm sorry it seems like there is someone from XBOX team has replied you that is a bug.